# How to switch off the released application in itunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Is it possible to remove a released and approved app in iTunes Connect? I want it to be unavailable in the App Store. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, go into iTunes Connect, then to Manage Your Applications. Select the application you want to remove and then select Rights and Pricing. Select the "Specific Stores" option, then deselect all countries to remove it from the store.

Once you are ready to have it back in the store follow the above steps, but select the countries you want the application to be available in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Go to iTunes Connect>Manage your applications>Your application page>Rights and Pricing. Here you can configure everything.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much! Don't got enough reputation to vote up :(